# strtotime("$target_date + 1 day") でなぜか月末になってしまう

Tags: php, laravel

PHP/Laravelで文字列の `YYYY-mm-dd` に１日加算した日付を取得したいのですが、なぜか月末が返されます。次の日を返したいのですが、どこを直せば良いでしょうか？

または別の良い方法があったら教えてください。

```
date("Y-n-t", strtotime("$test_date + 1 day"));
```

```
$original_date = "2022-11-05";
$test_date = $this->getNextDay(original_date);
Log::debug($test_date );
Log::debug($original_date );

private function getNextDay($target_date)
{
    return date("Y-n-t", strtotime("$target_date + 1 day"));
}
```

結果

```
[2022-06-11 03:24:41] local.DEBUG: 2022-11-30  
[2022-06-11 03:24:41] local.DEBUG: 2022-11-05
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date` の引数として指定されているフォーマット文字列が間違っています。
`t` は、指定した月の日数が返却されるものです。
そのため、日にちを取得したい場合は、 `date("Y-n-j");` のように指定する必要があります。

参考：
[PHP: DateTime::format - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/datetime.format.php)